# Security to the Party [Part 32!]

Tags: password

You once again decide to steal the recipe at the party! How many has this guy had now? Like 30? He really is rich. No wonder you want the recipe so bad!

This time the extravagant man has amped up on the security. The guard is still there, he still gives out numbers, but it seems the host is catching on to your trick. He's installed a keypad! So much for listening in on responses!

You still decide to try! You hide in the bushes and listen.

The first guest arrives. The guard said "53". You hear "BEEP!" And the doors open.

The second guest arrives. The guard said "32". You hear "BEEP!" And the doors open.

Realizing you're getting nowhere, you get a pair of binoculars and find a new hiding spot. The only problem is you can't hear them anymore!

The 3rd guest comes and you see him type in the letter "D". He's admitted.

Then a 4th guest appears and you seem him type in "E". The door opens - well at least the trap door: he falls down into an alligator pit. About 5 seconds after an elephant is dropped down too!

You find an old satellite and get to listen and hear. You only get to once though. No other guest comes after the 5th for a while, so you gave up.

The 5th guest gets the number "62" and types in "Q" to get let in.

You get down and the guard says "73" what do you type in to get admitted?

**BONUS: What were the audio/visual to the first 3 guests?**

Hints:

> A fellow puzzler fails and says F, now you know it isn't F, you stick around and find the answer to "33" is "I" You go back and you also get hit with 73!

Yes that is the hint form I'm going to use.

Comment: There are a very large number of possible answers. Without more information, it's impossible to justify which one is 'right'.

Comment: @user For every wrong answer I'll give a new video-audio thing for the **"next"** spy.

Comment: If I've read meta correctly, questions that don't start with enough information to have an answer are off-topic.

Comment: Well @user It may not be obvious to you, but this does contain enough information.

Comment: Does the form of your hint mean I have to get trampled by an elephant, and don't get a second chance unless I set up a new SE account?

Comment: @rand That probably wouldn't fit puzzling guidelines so just assume your a new spy.

Answer (score 5):

My (wrong) guess is F.

Reasoning: the answer to the number n is the (79-n)th letter of the alphabet, where 79-n is reduced mod 26.

So the questions and answers for the first five guests are 53 and Z, 32 and U, 75 and D, 74 and E, 62 and Q.

Comment: Nope. I guess I'm adding another equation.

Comment: [Please do not post an answer where all the content is hidden in spoiler markup](https://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/should-and-or-are-top-voted-answers-allowed-to-use-spoiler-tags/1424#1424). Your answer should make sense and be distinguishable from another answer to a reader who cannot or chooses not to read the spoiler block.

Comment: @Gilles - I guess this one is OK to despoilerify, since it's wrong. But hiding almost all the content in spoilers seems to be fairly standard practice here. Downvoting me for it seems a bit harsh! :-(

Answer (score 3):

The correct response to the number AB is the Bth letter on key#(A+1) on a standard telephone number pad.

You should type V, the first two guests typed O and H, and the third guest received 21.

Comment: @warspyking said "For every wrong answer I'll give a new video-audio thing", so if you're wrong he has to give *three* new ones! :->

Comment: Just pick an answer.

Comment: I'm not accepting 3 different answers.

Comment: Without more information, there's no way to distinguish between the first and second answers.

Comment: We have a winner!

Comment: This is so very close... Why A+1?

Comment: Because on a standard telephone keypad there aren't any letters on the 1 key, and Q is the second letter on the 7 key. http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/73/Telephone-keypad2.svg/571px-Telephone-keypad2.svg.png

Comment: [Please do not post an answer where all the content is hidden in spoiler markup](https://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/should-and-or-are-top-voted-answers-allowed-to-use-spoiler-tags/1424#1424). Your answer should make sense and be distinguishable from another answer to a reader who cannot or chooses not to read the spoiler block.

Comment: @user No one said it was a STANDARD telephone.

Comment: If it's not a standard telephone, there's absolutely no reason to choose it instead of the second answer I gave (which would result in an answer of U instead).